# Java Printing - Spooling in Printing Queue

Tags: java, printing

I want to print a pdf file to a printer using java-based software specifically Netbeans. When I ran my code below, I saw that the document is in printing queue with a file name **"Java Document"** with a **Spooling status**.

The questions are:

I want to know why my printer is not printing the document even if it is in queue?
Is it because of the code or is it because of my printer?

Here is my code:

```
    public String gonnaGo(String newfile) throws FileNotFoundException,   PrintException, IOException{

     System.out.println("Hello!" + newfile);
     InputStream is;
        is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(newfile)); //The new file will be the one to be printed
        Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(in, DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE,null);
        PrintService service = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
  // Locate the default print service for this environment.
            System.out.println("Default printer: " +    PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService().getName()); 
  //Check if the file  directory of the file to be printed is included

        PrintRequestAttributeSet params = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet(); //ADD PRINTING PROPERTIES HERE
        params.add(new Copies(1));

        DocPrintJob printJob = service.createPrintJob(); //used to determine whether the print job is finished
        printJob.addPrintJobListener(new JobCompleteMonitor());


        service.createPrintJob().print(doc, params);

        System.out.println("Exiting app");
        is.close();
    return null;        
        }
```

This is the output and it does not print anything. My printer is already connected. **I use Canon ip2770 series, Epson Stylus TX117, and HP Deskjet 2510 series with the latest drivers.** 
[image]

Comment: Look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jps/spec/jpsOverview.fm4.html and see if that answers some of your questions.

Comment: I tried using that way of print. It was successfully built, however, it doesn't appear on the printing queue. Is it because my printer is not pdf supported?